# Collision detection issue

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection

I am using InteractiveTileObject class as super class for Coin class,I set up worldContactListner class to listen for collision b/w the main body and coin object. The code given below for worldcontactlistner never goes to line which has; `System.out.println("Im here 2")` (in WorldContactListner class), I dont understand why, the coin class is a instance of InteractiveTileObject and should execute onCollision method, Please help me identify whats wrong.Code is given below;

```
public class Coin extends InteractiveTileObject {

    public Coin(World world, TiledMap map, Rectangle rectangle) {
        super(world, map, rectangle);
        fixture.setUserData(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCollision() {
        Gdx.app.log("Coin","Collision");
    }
}

public abstract class InteractiveTileObject {
    protected World world;
    protected TiledMap map;
    protected TiledMapTile tile;

    protected Body body;
    public Fixture fixture;


    public InteractiveTileObject(World world, TiledMap map, Rectangle rectangle) {


        this.world = world;
        this.map = map;
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        PolygonShape polygonShape = new PolygonShape();


        for (MapObject mapObject : map.getLayers().get(6).getObjects().getByType(RectangleMapObject.class)) {
            rectangle = ((RectangleMapObject) mapObject).getRectangle();
            bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
            bodyDef.position.set((rectangle.getX() + rectangle.getWidth() / 2) / trollVersusZombies.PPM, (rectangle.getY() + rectangle.getHeight() / 2) / trollVersusZombies.PPM);

            body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

            polygonShape.setAsBox(rectangle.getWidth() / 2 / trollVersusZombies.PPM, rectangle.getHeight() / 2 / trollVersusZombies.PPM);
            fixtureDef.shape = polygonShape;

            fixtureDef.isSensor = true;
            fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

        }


    }

    public abstract void onCollision();

}

public class WorldContactListener implements ContactListener {

    @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
        Fixture fixA = contact.getFixtureA();
        Fixture fixB = contact.getFixtureB();

        if( fixA.getUserData() == "body" || fixB.getUserData() == "body")
        {

            Fixture body = fixA.getUserData().equals("body") ? fixA : fixB;
            Fixture object = body == fixA ? fixB : fixA;
               System.out.println("Im here"); //Code comes here
            if(object.getUserData() instanceof InteractiveTileObject)
            {
                System.out.println("Im here 2"); //Code doesnt get here
                ((InteractiveTileObject)object.getUserData()).onCollision();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endContact(Contact contact) {

    }

    @Override
    public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {

    }

    @Override
    public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at `fixA.getUserData() == "body"` etc. - this might not work as intended and you should _always_ compare strings (and as a rule of thumb all objects) using the `equals()` method anyway, so use `"body".equals(fixA.getUserData())` (swapping the operands removes the need for null checks) etc.

Comment: `if( "body".equals(fixA.getUserData()) || "body".equals(fixB.getUserData()))
        {

            Fixture body = "body".equals(fixA.getUserData()) ? fixA : fixB;
            Fixture object = body == fixA ? fixB : fixA;
               System.out.println("Im here"); //Code comes here
            if(object.getUserData() instanceof InteractiveTileObject)
            {
                System.out.println("Im here 2"); //Code doesnt get here
                ((InteractiveTileObject)object.getUserData()).onCollision();
            }}`

Comment: @Thomas I editted the code to the code given above, it still doesnt work. Any help ?

Comment: @Thomas `Object.getUserData()` is giving me null pointer exception, as I tried to `System.out.println(Object.getUserData().toString())`

Comment: Well that means that at least some fixtures in your application don't have any user data - I doubt you only have a body and a coin in your world. If you are sure that `object` should refer to the coin's fixture then you should look for where that fixture's user data is being set. You didn't show where `fixture` is defined so there might be a chance that you're actually reusing the same fixture and overwrite the user data somehow.

Comment: `public class Coin extends InteractiveTileObject {

    public Coin(World world, TiledMap map, Rectangle rectangle) {
        super(world, map, rectangle);
        fixture.setUserData(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCollision() {
        Gdx.app.log("Coin","Collision");
    }
}`

@Thomas Im setting fixture user data as coin class, so that i can be later checked as instance of InteractiveTileObject..should I post the whole code of my project ? Can you help me?

Comment: I probably won't have time to debug your code and that's your task anyway. What I meant is that I have no idea where `fixture` comes from or where else it is being used. You basically reposted part of your question so no new information there. As I said, debug your code and check where `fixture` (I mean the actual field/variable, not the class itself) is being used and what happens to its user data.